# Python for loop comparisons

Tags: python, arrays

Forgive me if this question seems trivial but I have an array of strings in a for loop that's been sorted. There are some repeat items in the array that I want to remove. I'm fairly new to Python so I don't know if there's a library that lets me remove repeat items in an array. Here's what I'm doing to remove the repeat items:

```
for i in teams:
        if teams[i+1] is teams[i]:
                teams.remove(teams[i])
```

Now the if-statement in that would've worked just fine in C++, C#, and Java but for some reason it's returning an error "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects".

Comment: After you fix the index errors, be aware that mutating an object *while* you're iterating over it is quite unlikely to do what you hope.

Comment: If `teams` is a list of strings, I don't think `is` will necessarily do what you want either.  Use `==` to test strings for equality; `is` tests *identity*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove duplicate strings in a list you can use a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Convert the list to a set, convert it back to a list and then sort:

```
teams = ['big','small','big','foo','bar','bar','foo']
teams = sorted(list(set(teams)))

In [12]: teams
Out[12]: ['bar', 'big', 'foo', 'small']
```

The `set` doesn't allow for duplicates, it deals with the removing them for you. Also you are now sorting after duplicates have been removed instead of before, which should be more efficient.

Comment: You could also write `sorted(set(teams))`.

Comment: @DSM Thank you, that is so much better =D

Answer (score 5):

`i` is the *item* from `teams`. It's not an index. (Hint: when debugging this kind of problem, stick a `print(i)` inside the loop to make sure it's what you think it is.)

Now even after taking that into consideration, and rewriting your code to use a real index via either `enumerate()` or `range()`, you may still have some trouble, because you're removing items from the list *while* you're iterating over it. This will cause you to skip over some of them, because `for` is using an index internally and adds 1 to it each time through the loop. So deleting the current item moves the next-higher item into its place, then the index is incremented and the next one after *that* is now considered.

The most straightforward solution to *that* problem is to create a new list that contains only the elements you want to keep:

```
newteams = []
for team in teams:
    if not (newteams and newteams[-1] == team):
        newteams.append(team)
```

Basically, this will add a new item to `newteams` only if 1) `newteams` is empty or 2) the last item of `newteams` doesn't match the current team. Result: runs of duplicates of any length are reduced to a single item.  If this needs to modify the list `teams` in place, then use a slice assignment afterward:

```
teams[:] = newteams
```

Another approach is to use a `set` to keep track of items we've already seen. (We use a `set` because it's fast to check to see whether something is in it.) Then we can simply omit the items we've already seen *anywhere* in the list -- with the previous approach, the list would need to be sorted for that to happen.

```
seen = set()
newteams = []
for team in teams:
    if team not in seen:
        newteams.append(team)
    else:
        seen.add(team)
```

With a little abuse of Python, one can condense this to the following (though you probably shouldn't, especially as a newcomer to the language):

```
seen = set()
teams[:] = (seen.add(team) or team for team in teams if team not in seen)
```

Of course if you don't care about the order (or are willing to sort the list afterward) @RMcG`s solution of converting to a set and back is even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

groupby is a handy solution for this

```
from itertools import groupby
newteams = [k for k,g in groupby(teams)]
```

Comment: Nice, wouldn't have considered `groupby`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might have intended.

```
for i in range(len(teams)):
    if teams[i+1] == teams[i]:
            teams.remove(teams[i])
```

You shouldn't use `teams[i+1] is teams[i]` because `is` compares identity of the 2 objects being compared. Equality must be compared only by `==`.
Also, instead of `teams.remove(teams[i])` you must do `del teams[i]` since you are repeating the indexing while being aware of the index.

`i in items` would give you the elements in the items & not the index.

```
>>>teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3']
>>>for team in teams:
...    print team
team1
team2
team3
```

While

```
>>>teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3']
>>>for i in range(3):
...    print teams[i]
team1
team2
team3
```

You could also use builtin `enumerate` function

```
teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3']
for index, team in enumerate(teams):
    print index, "-->", team
```

Output of above

```
0 --> team1
1 --> team2
2 --> team3
```